# Wildfly 10 periodic log rotation

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am using Wildfly 10 (JBOSS) server. This is the my log rotation configuration in my server environment.

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

A log file (server.log.2018-mm-dd) is getting created daily with the above configuration. but the size of this file is very huge around 1.5 to 2gb. so i want to get a tar file created instead of direct file. what to add in the above configuration to get a zipped file created ?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality isn't available in WildFly 10 by default unfortunately. You could replace the `org.jboss.logmanager` module with 2.1.2.Final which contains an [enhancement](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-30) for this.

The only other option would be to add a cronjob or something similar to execute when the log is rotated.